# Variable not empty, when it should be empty?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$a = $_POST['a'];
$b = $_POST['b'];
$c;

if(is_numeric($a) && is_numeric($b)){
echo "string";
exit();
}

if(!is_numeric($a) && !is_numeric($b)) {
echo "string";
exit();
}

if(isset($a)){
$resultat=$b*2.54;
echo "string " . $c . " string";
exit();
}

if(isset($b)){
$resultat=$a/2.54;
echo "string " . $c . " string";
exit();
}
?>
```

I start by checking wether form field 1 & 2 hold nummeric values, then i check if both hold values.
That works fine, but when i get down to the second part, it never gets past the first "if" it always sees "a$" as set ...

Do i have to use case? or ?

Comment: Which part is the part that it never gets too (I couldn't quite follow). Also:  why do you think $a should be empty?

Comment: It gets input via a form, if the form is left empty, $a should be empty, it never gets past if(isset($a)), even if $a is not set and $b is set

Comment: `empty` and `isset` are different in PHP. A variable can be empty, but it is set if it is passed from your form.

Comment: isset will return true, even if a variable is empty.  It just checks for whether a variable is not null.

Comment: Ahh i see, i was uninformed then, what do you recomend i use?

Comment: Try using `!empty()` instead.

Comment: Take a look here:  http://techtalk.virendrachandak.com/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/   quite helpful, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting an empty string when you check `if(isset($a))`. The problem is that you are checking if it is set, not if it is empty. The variable is set in your first line, when you instantiate it. The form is passing an empty string to $_POST, so you should be checking that $a is not an empty string.

```
if ($a !== '') {
    $resultat=$b*2.54;
    echo "string " . $c . " string";
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically $a will always be set, since it is set to $_POST['a']. So it will be "set" every time, even if $_POST['a'] is empty. Try using this:

```
if (!empty($a))
```

That will check if $a is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

The variable $a will have the value of $_POST['a'], when this value is empty PHP will throw a notice error so the first thing you need to do is use isset.

```
$a = isset($_POST['a']) ? $_POST['a'] : null //Set $a to $_POST['a'] when NOT empty
```

The isset function in PHP will only returns true if the variable isn't set even when the value is null.

The second thing is to check if the value is null, the best thing you could do is use a loose comparison:

```
if ($a == null) {
    echo 'A is emty..';
}
```

This way the values: "", 0, null and false will be seen as "empty".

If you'd like to know if the value is actually null is a strict comparison which uses a triple "=":

```
if ($a === null) {
    echo 'A is empty';
}
```